# UITableViewCell delete does not use proper UITableViewRowAnimation

Tags: ios, uitableview

When a row is deleted it always slides to left no matter what animation value I pass. I would like it to slide up similar to many of the stock apps.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        self.tableData = [][[self.tableData mutableCopy] removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row] copy];

        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

    }
}
```

Here is the full tableview controller code, it is has a lot in it. That is the reason I didn't post it at first.

```
@interface FMListViewController ()
@property (strong) NSArray *currentLocations;
@property (assign) BOOL isEditing;
@end

@implementation FMListViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    UISegmentedControl *viewType = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"List", @"Map", nil]];
    CGRect viewTypeRect = viewType.frame;
    viewTypeRect.size.width = 150.0f;
    viewType.frame = viewTypeRect;
    viewType.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
    [viewType addTarget:self action:@selector(viewTypeChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = viewType;
    self.currentLocations = [[FMLocations sharedManager] allLocations];
    //watch for weather updates
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(weatherUpdated) name:@"weatherUpdated" object:nil];
    //watch for changes to saved locations
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(locationsUpdated) name:@"locationsUpdated" object:nil];
    self.isEditing = NO;

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // this UIViewController is about to re-appear, make sure we remove the current selection in our table view when swiping back occurs
    NSIndexPath *tableSelection = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:tableSelection animated:NO];
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:NO];

}


- (void)viewTypeChange:(UISegmentedControl *)segControl{
    NSLog(@"change to map");
    [(FMNavController *)[self navigationController] changeViewType];
    segControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)weatherUpdated{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
}

- (void)locationsUpdated{
    if(self.isEditing){
        self.currentLocations = [[FMLocations sharedManager] savedLocations];
    }else{
        self.currentLocations = [[FMLocations sharedManager] allLocations];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - Table Editing Stuff
- (IBAction)toggleEditing:(id)sender{
    if(self.isEditing){
        self.isEditing = NO;
        self.currentLocations = [[FMLocations sharedManager] allLocations];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        UIBarButtonItem *newRightItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(toggleEditing:)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = newRightItem;
        [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    }else{
        self.isEditing = YES;
        self.currentLocations = [[FMLocations sharedManager] savedLocations];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        UIBarButtonItem *newRightItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(toggleEditing:)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = newRightItem;
        [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    }

}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(indexPath.row == 0 && [[FMLocations sharedManager] currentLocation] && !self.isEditing){
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //add code here for when you hit delete
        NSMutableArray *newLocations;
        int arrayOffset = 0;
        if([[FMLocations sharedManager] currentLocation] && !self.isEditing){
            arrayOffset = -1;
        }
        newLocations = [[[FMLocations sharedManager] savedLocations] mutableCopy];
        int itemToRemove = (int)indexPath.row + arrayOffset;
        if(itemToRemove < 0 || itemToRemove > [newLocations count]){
            NSLog(@"invalid item to remove");
        }else{
            [newLocations removeObjectAtIndex:itemToRemove];
            [[FMLocations sharedManager] saveSavedLocations:[newLocations copy]];
            if(self.isEditing){
                self.currentLocations = [[FMLocations sharedManager] savedLocations];
            }else{
                self.currentLocations = [[FMLocations sharedManager] allLocations];
            }

            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

        }
    }
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(indexPath.row == 0 && [[FMLocations sharedManager] currentLocation] && !self.isEditing){
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath{
    NSMutableArray *editableLocations = [[[FMLocations sharedManager] savedLocations] mutableCopy];
    if(editableLocations && [editableLocations count] > sourceIndexPath.row && [editableLocations count] > destinationIndexPath.row){
        NSInteger fromIndex = sourceIndexPath.row;
        NSInteger toIndex = destinationIndexPath.row;

        id object = [editableLocations objectAtIndex:fromIndex];
        [editableLocations removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndex];
        [editableLocations insertObject:object atIndex:toIndex];
        [[FMLocations sharedManager] saveSavedLocations:[editableLocations copy]];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Refresh control action
- (IBAction)doRefreshTable:(id)sender{
    [[ForecastManager sharedManager] updateForecasts];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.currentLocations count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //NSLog(@"getting cell");
    FMTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FMLocationCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDictionary *theLocation = [self.currentLocations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // Configure the cell...
    cell.locationLabel.text = [[theLocation objectForKey:@"name"] uppercaseString];
    WeatherObject *locationWeather = [[ForecastManager sharedManager] weatherObjectForLocation:[[theLocation objectForKey:@"id"] intValue]];
    [cell setCurrentTemp:locationWeather.currentTemp];

    [cell configureForecastViews:locationWeather.forecastObjects];
    [cell.weatherPreviewContainer setNeedsDisplay];
    return cell;
}



#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showLocation"]){
        FMDetailViewController *detailController = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSDictionary *theLocation = [self.currentLocations objectAtIndex:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row];
        detailController.navigationItem.title = [theLocation objectForKey:@"name"];
        detailController.detailLocation = theLocation;
    }

}
```

Comment: please show us the full code...you might be deleting rows from somewhere else.

Comment: @Dev_Tandel all of the tableviewcontroller code added.

Comment: The code is correct. i can't find bug that may cause the issue.
jus t try tableView instead of self.tableview

Comment: i tried that and it made no difference. i am just living the animation for now, beat my head on the wall enough for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below solutions:

1) Replace your line with the below one

```
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

2) Change the code with the below one:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: neither of those worked. thanks. I had already tried the begin updates and end updates.

Answer (score 0):

please  try with that 
don't delete cell directly first make its cellheight to zero using.  `NSIndexPath *deleteIndexPath`;
wirte below code before delete

```
    [tbl beginUpdates];
    deleteIndexPath = indexPath;
    [tbl reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [tbl endUpdates];
```

and in set hight method use

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    if (indexPath == deleteIndexPath) {
    return 0;
}
return 50;
}
```

Comment: when making height to zero its give animation something like  slide up and there is no  slides to left animation in height changes

Comment: heightForRowAtIndexPath will be excited after the row is deleted from tableview and before end update setting height will not make any difference in that ...thats what i think ...you may try although..

Comment: have to write this line after size become zero
  [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

Comment: and for make delay in delete we can use  dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.01 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       // delete row code ;
    });

Comment: i don't think for this general problem it will be nice to do some trick...its better to find out the bug causing the issue.

Comment: yes i agree with you  
but if defaults are not working then we have to manage with ourself sometimes